# Interresting apacha2 problem (/var/www/hml)

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2

Hy Everyone!

I installed owncloud, and use the apache2 werbserver. I created /var/www/owncloud for the owncloud data files. Owncloud is working, i created useres and uploadad files inside owncloud.
I can connect to it only LAN. I have a ddns.net host and use it to reach my homserver. Configured the router to open and forward the port to my server.

Every time i try to connect from outside to my server http port, i get log message about that i dont have premisson to open the page what is in my /var/www/html map. The funny part of the storry is, that my DocumentRoot is in /var/www/owncloud. I changed it in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and in the 000-default.conf files too.
My apache2ctl -S that i have /var/www/html for DocumentRoot, but i dont have that in my config files. I dont known where else can is set my documentroot?
And more over, why can i connent to my ownclod from inside my home network - what is in my /var/www/owncloud - but from outside it changes somehow to /var/www/html?

Thank you if you have any advice!

Comment: It's hard to say anything without looking at your Apache config files.

Comment: apache2ctl -S is correct. I guess you missed something in your config. In /etc/apache2 issue grep -r 'DocumentRoot'. You might see the problem then.

Comment: Thx for the reply! I solved the problem, with moving my data to /var/www/html, but got no answer why i could not reach from outside. The looking after 'DocumentRoot' was every time my initial root place /var/www/owncloud. I trully miss something, but now i have another issue.

Comment: I bought an assus rt-ac68u, because of 5ghz. I connected my server with the server via utp cable so the family phones and laptos are connecting with wifi only. If i upload files to server whit the owncloud android app i get ~200Kb -500Kb upload speed. But if i upload files via ftp app to pureftp i got 2-3mb upload speed. The speed is low anyway but i dont get the diference, why? Apache is listeing on https, maybe the secure protocol slows it down? I created keys with letsecureit. Its a dumb question but i realy dont have any idea.. (my laptop has 8-13mb upload speed but never a stable number)

Comment: Edit: "I connected my server with the ROUTER via utp cable……"